# How to check with validate if a Value does exist per User that it is only once contained?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am creating a coffee shop website because I want to learn Laravel and I like coffee.
I have a dashboard where the user can manage his coffee. He can manually select from all kind of coffee. With my approach, I detect 2 Major Problems which is connected to the question.

**1. Problem**

Let's say the User has added 2 coffees with the id of 1 and 2

```
id  |  user_id  |  selected_coffee  |  created_at  |  updated_at
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1        |  1                |  xxxxxxxxxx  |  xxxxxxxxxx
1   |  1        |  2                |  xxxxxxxxxx  |  xxxxxxxxxx
```

If the User selects in these orders because he can select multiple. *** Let's say he select the coffee id 1, 2 and the last one 3.***

***Because the code detects that the first id is in the database, it is ignoring the other values.***

**2. Problem**

Let's say the User1 has added 2 coffees with the id of 1 and 2

```
id  |  user_id  |  selected_coffee  |  created_at  |  updated_at
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1        |  1                |  xxxxxxxxxx  |  xxxxxxxxxx
1   |  1        |  2                |  xxxxxxxxxx  |  xxxxxxxxxx
```

***The User2 can select the coffee but it is not written in the Database which I need for display visually on the frontend***

I know it is not well seen to add 2 Problems but my thought is if we can fix the number 1. The problem then the 2.Problem will disappear.

*Here is my code which makes it unique:*

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  app('App\Http\Controllers\ScoreController')->store($request);

  $message = ['selected_coffee.unique' => 'Check Coffee ID already exist'];
  $this->validate($request,[
    'selected_coffee' => 'unique:manage_coffees',
  ],$message);


  if($request->input('checkedDrink') != null){

    foreach ($request->input('checkedDrink') as $selected_id) {

      $manage_coffee = new ManageCoffee();

      $manage_coffee->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;

      $manage_coffee->selected_coffee = (int)$selected_id;

      $manage_coffee->save();

    }
  }

  return redirect('dashboard/coffee');
}
```

I found the validator in StackOverflow but it was not well explained. I think I must do a where clause in the *->validate* but I don't know where I should put it.

Hopefully, you guys can help me.

Torsten

Comment: About #1, what do you mean "code detect that the first id is in the database"? which id? please make sure that you have `auto increment` set for your main `id` column, and that `selected_coffee` and `user_id` has only regular index and not unique.

Comment: I mean the first id in ```selected_coffee```. Lets say user picks in the checkbox ```selected_coffee = 1, 2```. After that he selects by ```selected_coffee= 1,2,3```. The ID 3 would not be written row wised in the database. Auto Increment is already set. ```user_id``` is not set as unique it is an ```foreign key``` but ```selected_coffee``` is set unique because I want that the user can only select 1 coffee for each type. Lets say he selects Mokka Coffee, it will be displayed as card so if he selects again Mokka Coffee it will display it as 2 Mokka Coffee Card, which I really dont want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct you need [exist rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists) but with additional condition like in example from official docs.

Something like that:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$this->validate($request,[
   'selected_coffee' => [
       Rule::exists('manage_coffees')->where(function ($query) {
           $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
           //you can specify any conditions you like
       }),
   ],
],$message);
```